# Internet Explorer only shows background

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm developing my application and I ran into an issue. It works on all browsers except IE.

Anyways, this is how it should look (Editor View)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J414K.jpg

And this is how it looks in the Browser mode (and when I open it manually with IE):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3rqA.jpg

When there's no background image assigned, it shows up just fine.

This is my CSS property for the "body" div

```
body {
font: 80%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background: #4E5869;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-attachment: scroll;
color: #000;
background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3rqA.jpg);
}
```

Anyone has any suggestions?

This is the full HTML source code:

> http://pastebin.com/Qvq83f9H

Comment: What is "browser mode" and "editor mode"? Never seen that before in MS IE. Which software are you really talking about? Additionally, posting some images and plain, static HTML is not as useful as if you would have set up a working test case, e.g. using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: You should run your code through a validator like http://validator.w3.org/. It has some issues that might help clear things up.

Comment: It's an app I'm developing in VB.Net. Disregard that part. Even if I manually change the background-image:url() in Notepad it still doesn't show right in IE. So, my main problem is CSS property for background image.

Comment: You have 14 validation errors when I checked. Fix them, then we will try to help. IE really doesn't like errors. I glanced at a few of them and some were a cause for concern. Things like opening and closing tags not matching.

Answer (score 1):

your JS has  a Problem Solve it

```
 <!--window.onload= function (){if( ! getCookie("ok") ) {   showInfo(document.getElementById('welcome').innerHTML); }}
```

You Can't commented js code by **< !--** You must put **//**

```
 //window.onload= function (){if( ! getCookie("ok") ) { showInfo(document.getElementById('welcome').innerHTML); }}
```

Comment: You certainly don't have to put the JavaScript after the body. The problem is that there's an unclosed HTML comment within the script, which is clearly shown via JS Fiddle's syntax highlighting.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse I Test it if Move js To End Of Body Problem Solve

Comment: Yes it will, but it doesn't fix the root cause, it merely allows IE to make sense of the code.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse You Are Right Problem Is For < !-- on last line of js